# PyQt popup on right click wont disappear after selection

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I am trying to have a 'right-click' pop up menu on a matplotlib canvas which also updates the cursor position on a window label when the mouse just hovers over a pixel.  The problem is, that if I right click, it brings up the menu as expected.  Then after making a selection as soon as I hover the mouse or even left-click anywhere on the canvas the popup keeps reappearing - behaving as if I have right-clicked again when I haven't.  Its almost as if I have to flush the event or reset its state back to 'not clicked' I have to following code.  But I can't figure out how to make it work.

If I don't update the mouse position on the GUI when hovering, it works fine.  But as soon as I try and have the dynamic update it works until I right-click the first time.

```
self.cidpress = self.ui.mplWidget.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.get_mouse_coords)
```

And

```
def get_mouse_coords(self, event):
    """
    Updates the GUI with the mouse coordinates and the parameter value

    :param event: event handler from Matplotlib.
    """
    pos = QtGui.QCursor().pos()

    if event.button == 3:
        self.open_menu(pos)

    if isinstance(event.xdata, float) and isinstance(event.ydata, float):
        self.ui.lbl_x_pos.setText('X : ' + str(round(event.xdata, 3)))
        self.ui.lbl_y_pos.setText('Y : ' + str(round(event.ydata, 3)))
    try:
        self.ui.lbl_param_pos.setText('P :' +
                                      str(self.parameter_stats[self.output_parameter][int(event.xdata)][
                                          int(event.ydata)]))
    except:
        self.ui.lbl_param_pos.setText('P : ' + 'None')
```

And

```
def open_menu(self, position):
    """
    Open a menu to let the user to save the file or to fit a curve at this position

    :param position: QT mouse position instance
    """

    #======================================#
    #  Add menus to action list
    #======================================#
    menu = QtGui.QMenu()
    save_action = menu.addAction("Save Image"),
    fit_curve_action = menu.addAction("Fit Curve")

    #======================================#
    #  Bring up Action list at the mouse position and call the appropriate function
    #======================================#
    action = menu.exec_(self.tableWidget.mapFromGlobal(position))
    if action == save_action:
        self.gt = lib_hdf_image_stats.GeoTiffTools()
        try:
            self.gt.write_to_geotiff(self.parameter_stats[self.output_parameter], self.pos_crnrs,
                                     [self.dict_list[0].delta_lat, self.dict_list[0].delta_lon],
                                     str(self.output_file_name))
        except:
            self.lg.exception('Error saving file :: Check file name')
    elif action == fit_curve_action:
        print('!Fit action')
```